# Minimize graphic effects for better performance?

Tags: macbook-pro, gpu

My computer becomes extremely slow when I connect TWO 27-inch thunderbold screens to it - a Macbook Pro Late 2013 (16Gb Ram/2.7 quad-core/Yosomite 10.10.1).
I am suspecting that the graphic card (NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M 1024 MB) isn't strong enough to drive the 3 screens (including the built-in Retina). 
I am looking for a way to minimize all graphic effects to speed my computer up. 
Anyone have a (possible) solution? 
Thanks in advance for reading and providing with suggestions. 
Best.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to system preferences, accessibility, display and check reduce transparency[image: accessibility]

You can also lower the resolution on the external monitors in the system preferences,displays menu.
and make sure automatic graphic switching is turned on in system preferences, energy saver[image: energy saver]
And try setting the wallpaper to a solid color.

Comment: Thank you. I've tried it but doesn't help much.